# python requests ssl error 550

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I've been trying to login to site using python 3.3 and requests, but I couldn't get that far. When ever i try to go to that page I get unknown _ssl.c:550 error. Google and other pages work just fine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 478, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 285, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1065, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1103, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1061, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 906, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 95, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util.py", line 634, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ssl.py", line 245, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ssl.py", line 345, in __init__
    raise x
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ssl.py", line 341, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\ssl.py", line 548, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] unknown error (_ssl.c:550)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 324, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 502, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL] unknown error (_ssl.c:550)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tomas\Documents\Dropbox\python\web_login.py", line 8, in <module>
    page = requests.get(url, verify=False)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 382, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 485, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 379, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL] unknown error (_ssl.c:550)
```

Here is script I tried.

```
import requests


url = "https://klevas.vu.lt/"
page = requests.get(url, verify=False)


print (page.content)
```

Changing url to `https://www.klevas.vu.lt` (added www) results in different error: `class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11004]`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 478, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 285, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1065, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1103, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1061, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 906, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 73, in connect
    timeout=self.timeout,
  File "C:\Python33\lib\socket.py", line 417, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 324, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 528, in urlopen
    raise MaxRetryError(self, url, e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.klevas.vu.lt', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tomas\Documents\Dropbox\python\web_login.py", line 7, in <module>
    page = requests.get(url, verify=False)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 382, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 485, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 372, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.klevas.vu.lt', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)
```

Comment: The version with `www` doesn't work, because the domain does not exist. (`getaddrinfo` failed)

Comment: the www version doesnt work in browser too, you are right, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example to what @sigmavirus24 meant:
(It's taken literally from the the linked blog post, only `PROTOCOL_SSLv3` is used

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
import ssl

class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', MyAdapter())

print(s.get('https://klevas.vu.lt/'))
```

The server you are talking to is an application server from oracle. When searching for it's server identificator you get links to a lot of bugtrackers of open source projects running into this bug -.-

Comment: This definitely works: @sigmavirus24 and I were just discussing it in IRC. As always, thanks for providing the solution before we got around to it!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with openssl which is what Python's `ssl` module relies on (and which in turn `requests` relies on). The way to verify this is by using the openssl `s_client` command to check this:

```
~/sandbox/requests (master) openssl s_client -connect klevas.vu.lt:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
140721982121664:error:140773E8:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1000):s23_clnt.c:741:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 319 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

That's the same error I see when testing this on python 2.7.

Furthermore, if I test the second url `www.kleavs.vu.lt` I get this:

```
~/sandbox/requests (master) openssl s_client -connect www.klevas.vu.lt:443
connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=111
```

Which is the same thing I see when I try to request the second URL via requests on either Python 2 or 3.

This is not an issue with requests but similar bugs have been filed: [#606](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/606) (which is where I pulled the openssl command).

You can attempt to follow the instructions [here](https://lukasa.co.uk/2013/01/Choosing_SSL_Version_In_Requests/) to determine if a different version of TLS or SSL will fix this for you, but I'm not sure it will help in this case.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out direction. Im beginner coder/scripter, that site wasnt too much of a help. I copy/pasted (dont know if correctly) and this time got this error:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140773E8:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1000)

Answer (score 0):

1. The solution from t-8ch misses the promised link.
2. This solution need extra modules which were neither described nor linked.

I found that at least with Xubuntu 14.04 you need to install these modules to get the code running:
a. python3-requests (http://github.com/kennethreitz/requests)
b. python3-urllib3 (http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest)

Then I needed to modify the code a little bit: 
from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
rather than
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
import ssl

class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', MyAdapter())

print(s.get('https://klevas.vu.lt/'))
```

returns

```
<Response [200]>
```